# Any details accessible for a message published to an SNS Topic while it had no subscriptions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I have an SNS Topic that had no subscriptions for a period of time.  So any messages published to that topic *during that period* when there were no subscriptions were essentially lost.  I am wondering if there are any logs or other records I could access to glean any info on things that could have been published during the time when there were no subscriptions.

I saw from [an AWS forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=104716) that

> "From [the AWS] perspective, a publish is successful if we
> successfully process the publish API call. We do not enumerate the
> subscriptions list until later. If there are no subscriptions to a
> topic, the message is eventually dropped."

I believe I could create a CloudWatch alarm to monitor the NumberOfMessagesPublished metric, per [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html).  From that article, I understand that Amazon SNS automatically sends the NumberOfMessagesPublished metric to CloudWatch, so if that metric shows nothing (count = 0) during the time period, I at least would have evidence of the *lack* of anything published to the topic.  But if something *was* published, is there any evidence that remains--in logs or elsewhere--of the message that was published?

Comment: Can you attach a SQS queue so effectively you have a Dead Letter Queue of messages that may or may not have gone out?

Comment: In general that is the right approach to avoid this situation, but I can't go back in time to do that, so I am wondering if there are any details I might still be able to glean from that period when there was nothing subscribed.